# Java - changing data fields?

Tags: java, methods, datafield

There are two things I need help with but I'm having a hard time figuring out. They are listed below - any assistance is greatly appreciated.

1) I need to add a method that prompts the user to enter an int (1-3) to change the volume (default set to 2). I'm really having trouble figuring out how to make this work.

2) I need to add a similar method that prompts the user to enter an int (1 or 2) to plug the head phones in.

Here's my code; one is the test class:

```
//Open Package
package headphone_wk6;

//Import scanner since this will require user input
import java.util.Scanner;


// Creat class for headphones
public class HeadPhone_WK6 {

//Call scanner
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

//Initialize input variable
int Input;

//Declare constant Variables
public static final int LOW = 1;
public static final int MEDIUM = 2;
public static final int HIGH = 3;

//Declare Private variables
private int volume;
private boolean pluggedIn;
private String manufacturer;
private String headPhoneColor;

//Declare Strings
String pluggedInStat;
String volumeNow;


// Constructor for class
public HeadPhone_WK6(int volume, boolean pluggedIn, String manufacturer, String headPhoneColor) {
    this.volume = volume;
    this.pluggedIn = pluggedIn;
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.headPhoneColor = headPhoneColor;
}

// Default Constructor for default settings
public HeadPhone_WK6() {
    volume = MEDIUM;
    pluggedIn = false;
    manufacturer = "";
    headPhoneColor = "";
}

// setVolume
public void setVolume(int volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
}

// getVolume
public int getVolume() {
    if (volume == 1) {
        volumeNow = "LOW";
    }
    else if (volume == 2) {
        volumeNow = "MEDIUM";
    }
    else {
        volumeNow = "HIGH";
    }
    return volume;
}


// setPluggedIn
public void setPluggedIn(boolean pluggedIn) {
    this.pluggedIn = pluggedIn;   
}

// getPluggedIn
public boolean getPluggedIn() {
    if(pluggedIn == true) {
        pluggedInStat = "Plugged In";
    }
    else {
        pluggedInStat = "Not Plugged In";
    }

    return pluggedIn;
}


// setManufacturer 
public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

// getManufacturer
public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}

// setHeadPhoneColor
public void setHeadPhoneColor(String headPhoneColor) {
    this.headPhoneColor = headPhoneColor;
}

// getHeadPhoneColor
public String getHeadPhoneColor() {
    return headPhoneColor;
}

// method to create string
public String toString() {

    boolean phonesPluggedIn = this.getPluggedIn();
    String phoneManufacturer = this.getManufacturer();
    String phoneColor = this.getHeadPhoneColor();
    String currentVolume = this.volumeNow;

    //Build String for characteristics of phones
    StringBuilder characteristics = new StringBuilder();
    characteristics.append(String.format("\nThe Head Phone Manufacturer "
            + "is: %s", phoneManufacturer));
    characteristics.append(String.format("\nThe Color of the Head Phone Set "
            + "is: %s", phoneColor));
    characteristics.append(String.format("\nThe Head Phones are Currently: "
            + " %s", phonesPluggedIn));
    characteristics.append(String.format("\nThe Head Phone Volume is "
            + "Currently Set on: %s", currentVolume));

    //return string for characteristics
    return characteristics.toString();


}
```

}

```
package headphone_wk6;

//Import scanner since this will require user input
import java.util.Scanner;

//Test class for head phone
public class HeadPhone_WK6_Test {

//Command line arguments
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Initialize input variable
    int Input;

    //Call scanner
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    HeadPhone_WK6 bestPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(2, false, "SONY", "BLUE");
    HeadPhone_WK6 worstPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(2, false, "BOSE", "BLACK");
    HeadPhone_WK6 decentPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(2, false, "RCA", "ORANGE");

    int bestPairVolume = bestPair.getVolume();
    boolean bestPairPluggedIn = bestPair.getPluggedIn();
    String bestPairManufacturer = bestPair.getManufacturer();
    String bestPairHeadPhoneColor = bestPair.getHeadPhoneColor();     
    String bestPairVolumeNow = bestPair.volumeNow;
    String bestPairPluggedInStat = bestPair.pluggedInStat;

    int worstPairVolume = worstPair.getVolume();
    boolean worstPairPluggedIn = worstPair.getPluggedIn();
    String worstPairManufacturer = worstPair.getManufacturer();
    String worstPairHeadPhoneColor = worstPair.getHeadPhoneColor();
    String worstPairVolumeNow = worstPair.volumeNow;
    String worstPairPluggedInStat = worstPair.pluggedInStat;

    int decentPairVolume = decentPair.getVolume();
    boolean decentPairPluggedIn = decentPair.getPluggedIn();
    String decentPairManufacturer = decentPair.getManufacturer();
    String decentPairHeadPhoneColor = decentPair.getHeadPhoneColor();
    String decentPairVolumeNow = decentPair.volumeNow;
    String decentPairPluggedInStat = decentPair.pluggedInStat;

    //Introduce HeadPhone helper
    System.out.print("Hi there! Let's have you try a pair of head phones "
            + "on and we'll see what you think of them! \nStart by choosing a "
            + "random pair of head phones. To do this, enter 1, 2, or 3: ");

    //Get user input for random pair of headphones
            Input = stdin.nextInt();

            //Loop for random headphone selection
            if (Input == 1){

                //echo user input
                System.out.println("You have chosen the best pair of "
                        + "headphones! Here is a list of the characteristics: ");

                System.out.println(bestPair.toString());

            //End if
            }

            else if (Input == 2){
                System.out.println("You have chosen the worst pair of "
                        + "headphones. Here is a list of the characteristics: ");

                System.out.println(worstPair.toString());


            //End If   
            }

            else if(Input == 3){
                System.out.println("You have chosen a decent pair of "
                        + "headphones. Here is a list of the characteristics:");

               System.out.println(decentPair.toString());

            //End If    
            }

            else{ 
                System.out.println("You have expressed that you want to see "
                        + "the default pair of headphones. They are the "
                        + "decent pair! Here's a list of the characteristics:");

                System.out.println(decentPair.toString());

            }






}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this, first get input via scanner, then create HeadPhone objects:

```
//Initialize input variable
    int Input;

    //Call scanner
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Introduce HeadPhone helper
    System.out.print("Hi there! Let's have you try a pair of head phones "
            + "on and we'll see what you think of them! \nStart by choosing a "
            + "random pair of head phones. To do this, enter 1, 2, or 3: ");

    //Get user input for random pair of headphones
    Input = stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Now give me value of plug in 1 or 2");
    int plugInState = stdin.nextInt();
    boolean pluggedIn=true;
    if(plugInState==1) pluggedIn = false;
    if(plugInState==2) pluggedIn = true;
    System.out.println("Now give me value volume (1/2/3");
    int volumeState = stdin.nextInt();
    HeadPhone_WK6 bestPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(volumeState, pluggedIn, "SONY", "BLUE");
    HeadPhone_WK6 worstPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(volumeState, pluggedIn, "BOSE", "BLACK");
    HeadPhone_WK6 decentPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(volumeState, pluggedIn, "RCA", "ORANGE");
```

You can put if clause in the end, based on your `input`, you can create one object that you need. If you need separate methods, do this in main():

```
        HeadPhone_WK6 hp = new HeadPhone_WK6();
    //Initialize input variable
    int Input;

    //Call scanner
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Introduce HeadPhone helper
    System.out.print("Hi there! Let's have you try a pair of head phones "
            + "on and we'll see what you think of them! \nStart by choosing a "
            + "random pair of head phones. To do this, enter 1, 2, or 3: ");

    //Get user input for random pair of headphones
    Input = stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Now give me value of plug in 1 or 2");
    int plugInState = stdin.nextInt();
    hp.setPluggedIn(plugInState);

    System.out.println("Now give me value volume (1/2/3");
    int volumeState = stdin.nextInt();
    hp.setVolume(volumeState);
    HeadPhone_WK6 bestPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(hp.getVolume(), hp.getPluggedIn(), "SONY", "BLUE");
    HeadPhone_WK6 worstPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(hp.getVolume(), hp.getPluggedIn(), "BOSE", "BLACK");
    HeadPhone_WK6 decentPair = new HeadPhone_WK6(hp.getVolume(), hp.getPluggedIn(), "RCA", "ORANGE");
```

Where

`setPluggedIn(int pluggedInState) {
            if(plugInState==1) pluggedIn = false;
        else if(plugInState==2) pluggedIn = true;
        else {
            pluggedIn = false;
        }
    }`

Comment: I really like you're answer, and I absolutely appreciate your help! The only problem is - I'm supposed to have the volume and pluggedIn set at default values of 2(medium) and false(unplugged). Is there any way to do this while also having default values set?

Comment: And also, how would I incorporate the print to String() with this? There has to be a way to print the string of characteristics based on the user selected headphones....

Comment: Well, you declared default values with an empty constructor so i don't see what are you pointing at? And how did you mean to incorporate? I mean - you used input to declare an object, an object has its toString() method based on its values that you already input.

Comment: True - didn't think about that. Sorry, I'm still really new to this; hopefully I'll catch on one day, but the resources our professor provides are often difficult to follow along with, especially for someone like me who doesn't like to read 100 pages every week. Thanks for your help!